# Can a User Defined Type reference another user defined type in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

In the following code sample there is an 'address' type and the insert works fine.  However if I add an additional attribute to the address type (*new_attribute*) which maps to a *new_attribute* type  and then insert into the user_profiles profiles I get an error not compatible with type map. Pretty new to Cassandra so any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TYPE new_attribute (
      name text,
      *map_l list<text>*
  );


CREATE TYPE address (
      street text,
      city text,
      zip int, 
      *new_attribute map<text, FROZEN<list<new_attribute>>>*
  );

  CREATE TABLE user_profiles (
      login text PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text,
      last_name text,
      email text,
      addresses map<text, frozen<address>>
  );

  // Inserts a user with a home address
  INSERT INTO user_profiles(login, first_name, last_name, email, addresses)
  VALUES ('tsmith',
          'Tom',
          'Smith',
          'tsmith@gmail.com',
          { 'home': { street: '1021 West 4th St. #202',
                      city: 'San Fransisco',
                      zip: 94110 ,
                      *new_attribute: [{'name': 'some value',
                                        map_l: ['list', 'of',    'text']}]}});*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact error is, but this is supported (at least in more current versions of Cassandra). I think you just have an error in the CQL literal of that attribute. All those nested collections are mind-bending. Here is a working literal:

```
INSERT INTO user_profiles(login, first_name, last_name, email, addresses)
  VALUES ('tsmith',
          'Tom',
          'Smith',
          'tsmith@gmail.com',
          {'home': {street: '1021 West 4th St. #202',
                    city: 'San Fransisco',
                    zip: 94110 ,
                    new_attribute: {'key': [{name: 'some value', 
                                             map_l: ['list', 'of', 'text']}]}}});
```

Comment: You're right.. it seems there was a CQL error.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the simple quotes around **name: 'some value'**

This is very tricky but UDT literal is slightly different from map literal with CQL:

Map literal : `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}`

UDT literal : `{field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}`